# Getting paid by my own disregarded entity in Idaho, do I need to file an Idaho personal income tax return

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, state-income-tax, sole-proprietorship, idaho

No physical assets nor contracts in Idaho itself. I do not live or physically present in Idaho. So reading through the income tax [documents](https://tax.idaho.gov/i-2014.cfm):

> Idaho source income is income from:
>
> - Transactions or activities that take place in Idaho

Does this include transactions conducted by my LLC's bank account which resides in Idaho (address on the bank account, bank itself is national) when paying myself (my own bank is not in Idaho) obligating me to file an Idaho annual income tax return?

PS: I'm asking Idaho specifics since every state has a slightly different taxation law. Also I'm aware of disregarded entity nature here, but this question is asking about my own annual income tax return which is separate from any, if at all, of my business(s) tax returns.